# How to change "John Doe's Test Store" business name in the PayPal sandbox?

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I am integrating PayPal with my platform in sandbox mode.

I want to rename "John Doe's Test Store" (pictured below) with the name of my platform.

I would also like to rename "John Doe's Test Store" in the second image below, with the name of my platform.

How can this be done?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the account's business name, log into that receiving sandbox Business account via https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/aboutBusiness

(If you need to change the sandbox account's password, do so from [PayPal Developer](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F))

---

To change the displayed business name for a particular transaction, set the v2/orders REST API [application_context object's](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_application_context) `brand_name` parameter, or the old classic API's BRANDNAME parameter.  This is mainly useful if you have multiple websites/storefronts going to one PayPal account.

Comment: ,Can you please explain with easy word and every step how to do it, for people with not experience?

Answer (score 1):

I found this, (but I am not able to edit more than two characters of the name, its asking me to upload proof. Please leave a comment, if you found a work around for this)

1. Login to sandbox business Account
2. Click username on top right and chose account settings
3. Open Business information(Screenshot below)

[image]

Here you can edit the details by clicking the update button

reference : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/1313